# Efficient database querying Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I'm using Rails 4 with PostgreSQL, and I have a table Quotes gets populated at random times. Sometimes two entries are milliseconds apart, sometimes hours (end of trading day). I'd like to build a graph of quotes over the past 1 year.

Right now I am using

```
quotes = Quote.where(:created_at => 1.year.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day).select(:price, :created_at)
```

and this works great, but I don't need (or want) all data with millisecond accuracy. I'd like to poll the database for only 1 quote every, say, 1 hour, but I'm not sure how to construct the query. I can of course get all the quotes from the database, then parse them and throw away most, but this seems like a waste of resources and time.

Also, please let me know if this seems like a terribly inefficient way to get quotes from the database. As a side note, the database servers are set up in a master-slave configuration with these quotes read requests coming from the slave.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution yet, and I haven't fully benchmarked it, but I thought I'd put it out there to maybe help others in a similar situation. Please correct me if this is not a well-formed query.

```
def get_quotes_3months(stock_symbol)    
    @results = []
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
            ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["
            select price, created_at, symbol
            from (
                select price, created_at, symbol,
                       row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('hour', created_at) order by created_at) as r
                from quotes
                ) as dt
            where r = 1 AND created_at BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '3 month' AND current_timestamp AND symbol = ?;", stock_symbol]
        )).each do |record|

            @results << {price: record["price"], created_at: record["created_at"].to_datetime}
        end
    return @results
end
```

Basically I partitioned the table into groups by hour, then ordered each group by created_at and took the first row in each group. I also sanitized the query because the input will be coming from a javascript ajax request (which is sanitized prior to this step, but I built in redundancy just in case).

The one last thing to figure out is how to change the partition to group by other time ranges (i.e. if I want one quote every 15 minutes, then calling date_trunc('15 minute', created_at) doesn't make sense.